# Is there a way to get nunit to accept A TestCaseSource Method that is async?

Tags: c#, nunit, .net-framework-version

NUnit doesn't seem to accept TestCaseSources that are async methods. Is there a workaround to this or is it a known issue in NUnit?

Comment: Show an example where this is really needed. It sounds like you want to retrieve testdata in that method from an async source. That sounds like something to avoid in a unittest.

Comment: Taking a second look at the code I realized we shouldn't have been using the async code. A developer was basically sneakily trying to test more than one method with the same test. My TestDataSource is simpler now, I did have an icky feeling about needing this I should have listened to my gut.